# How to test Calendar Event on emulator?

Tags: android, calendar, android-emulator

I am developing an application which requires to add Calendar event. I have written the code for inserting event to the calendar. But whenever i run my application, everytime i get error that "Fail to find provider info for Calendar" and it also throws me **NullPointerException** error. So, what it means and i found that emulator doesn't provide Calendar application in-built.

I think if the Android Emulator doesn't have Calender API, so, naturally, it will not have any database URI in the emulator whereas the Contact has URI **--"content://contacts/people".** I also found the URI for Calendar as **"content://calendar/calendars"** but it doesn't work and it means that it gives me error cause of missing Calendar application.

Can anybody clarify me, with suggestions regarding Calendar Event?

Which is the way to test my application with Calendar Event?

Comment: As you pointed out emulator has no Calendar apk, you have to compile and load it yourself. Let me know if you find an easy forum for that, as I am looking into that too.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Thanks for commenting to my topic.

Actually, there is no need of Calendar API in my application. I had gone through the link suggested by you and i knew that first i have to setup/ synchronize my email account to my device and after that i can proceed further.

But the Calendar application and content provider are available on Android handsets with Google services, such as the T-Mobile G1. So, naturally, it is not included in the emulator.

Thanks.

Regards,

---

Pranav

Comment: Read the StackOverFlow FAQ, you are not supposed to post answer like this. You should use the Add Comment section to reply on answers.

Comment: this is not an answer for your question!!

Answer (score 5):

> I am developing an application which
>   requires to add Calendar event. I have
>   written the code for inserting event
>   to the calendar. But whenever i run my
>   application, everytime i get error
>   that "Fail to find provider info for
>   Calendar" and it also throws me
>   NullPointerException error. So, what
>   it means and i found that emulator
>   doesn't provide Calendar application
>   in-built.

Do not attempt to manipulate the Calendar content provider. [That is not part of the SDK](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/12/14/code-pollution-reaching-past-the-sdk/). If you need to manipulate the user's calendars, do so through the [Google Calendar Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/), please.

Comment: How do I assign my calendar on Emulator with a Gmail account?

Comment: You can set it up under the preferences.